# How can I see what TSQL Entity Framework is generating for a query?

Tags: t-sql, entity-framework

Imagine this linq query:

```
return db.Projects.Where(p => p.ProjectID == id);
```

How can I see what TSQL it's generating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/)

You can see your queries as lambda expressions or SQL

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server profiler does exactly this. If you are on SQL Server Express, there is an open source alternative called [AnjLab Sql Profiler](http://sites.google.com/site/sqlprofiler/) since SQL server profiler isn't included with express.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach the Sql Server Profiler to your database while running the query. Furthermore, have a look at the [tracing and caching utility](https://web.archive.org/web/20160214193554/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/jkowalski/archive/2009/06/11/tracing-and-caching-in-entity-framework-available-on-msdn-code-gallery.aspx) for EF.

Comment: Woah! Over my head there. I don't know what a SQL Server Profiler is or how I would attach it. :S

Comment: @Serg, It's a program that is installed with Sql Server. It is super easy to use. It's in program files -> Microsoft Sql Server -> Performance tools